# How should I handle Products with different attributes in my database structure?

Tags: mysql, database-design, eav

We have an *e-commerce* site (web application) built with PHP.

There are different types of *products* like *mobiles, tshirts, watches, books.*

- A *mobile* can have attributes like, for example, *ram, model name, os*.
- A *t-shirt* can have attributes like, for instance, *color, size*.

My questions are the following:

1. Is it better to save all attributes in a single table called `Products` (even if there will be/it will create a lot of `'NULL'` marks)?
2. Save different types of products in different tables like `Mobiles`, `Tshirts`, etc.?

In the second case, more tables will be created, see the two images below:

[image: Diagram 1]

[image: Diagram 2]

As suggested via comments, I am using the EAV model, so I drew the following design [ image 3 ] :

[image]

as suggested in answer, instead of eav , i combined all 3 tables in one table as   `product_information + attributes_list + attributes_values = products information` i drew all in one table  [image 4 ]:

[image]

Please suggest me is i need to go with image 3 or image 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can also do, is following. You create a table with three columns: product_id, property and value. So you get not more tables then neccessary. But it's a matter of taste.